# Easiest way to combine columns of different (lengthy) SQL statements - MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple queries to combine, all of which have their own joining which would be very hard to re-write and bind together. Is there an easy way to combine the results of multiple statements, treating them in blocks?

Example:

**Query 1**

```
WITH Table1a AS (...)
WITH Table2a AS (...)
SELECT multiple_arguments FROM multiple_joined_tables
```

Resulting in a table like below

| User | ID | DatasetA | Other Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 1 | dataA1 | other_data1 |
| Test2 | 2 | dataA2 | other_data2 |
| Test3 | 3 | dataA3 | other_data3 |
| Test4 | 4 | dataA4 | other_data4 |

**Query 2**

```
WITH Table1a AS (...)
WITH Table2b AS (...)
WITH Table3c AS (...) 
SELECT multiple_arguments FROM multiple_joined_tables
```

Resulting in a table like below

| User | ID | DatasetB | More Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 1 | dataB1 | more_data_1 |
| Test2 | 2 | dataB2 | more_data_2 |
| Test3 | 3 | dataB3 | more_data_3 |
| Test4 | 4 | dataB4 | more_data_4 |
| Test5 | 5 | dataB5 | more_data_5 |

For a general number of `N` queries, how can I label them to re-use them later on and bind them as I wish so I can put columns together in a final table? Example

| User | ID | DatasetA | DatasetB | Some Other Data | Some More Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 1 | dataA1 | dataB1 | other_data1 | more_data_1 |
| Test2 | 2 | dataA2 | dataB2 | other_data2 | more_data_2 |
| Test3 | 3 | dataA3 | dataB3 | other_data3 | more_data_3 |
| Test4 | 4 | dataA4 | dataB4 | other_data4 | more_data_4 |
| Test5 | 5 | NULL | dataB5 | NULL | more_data_5 |

I am having trouble placing (WITH Table1 and Query 1) inside another WITH to use later on, and also binding them with UNION because of different columns, so I would like to see a **general** query of neatly labelling and binding them please. Thank you.

Comment: Use views or stored procedures that produce temp tables?

Comment: Can you show how? I am not familiar. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE can refer to other CTEs that have come before it. So you have two ways of doing what you want. Either "nest" the CTEs, or just refer to all of the CTEs in the final query.

Personally I would usually go with option 2, because "nesting" CTEs sometimes seems to produce a suboptimal query plan. But if option 1 makes the code more maintainable in your particular case, go ahead and try it out, just keep an eye on performance.

Below is an example with both methods. Obviously I would expect that the queries inside your CTE's are much more complex (otherwise there'd be no need for the CTEs, we would just join tables `T` and `U` directly). I'm keeping it simple to demonstrate the method.

```sql
create table T (i int, t char);
create table U (i int, u char);

-- option 1: combine in CTEs

with 
   MyT as 
   (
      select i, t from T
   ),                                 -- note the comma here, and no additional "with"
   MyTandU as 
   (
      select   MyT.i,
               MyT.t,
               U.u
      from     MyT                    -- referring to the previous CTE
      join     U     on U.i = myT.i
   )

select i, t, u from MyTandU;


-- option 2: combine final select

with 
   MyT as (select i, t from T),
   MyU as (select i, u from U)

select MyT.i, MyT.t, MyU.u
from   MyT
join   MyU on MyU.i = MyT.i
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a view.  With a view you can take an query result and give it a name --- you can then reuse that name as you would use a table.

Take your first query and make it a view.  You can use it in your second query.